# uploading files via graphql, setting up server and client sides and querying via curl, postman, and client react app

Tags: curl, file-upload, graphql

How to upload files via graphql and curl?  Getting errors like F: command not found

```
 curl http://localhost:8888/graphql \  
-F operations='{ "query": "mutation($files: [Upload!]!) { multipleUpload(files: $files) { id, name, content } }", "variables": { "files": [null, null] } }' \
-F map='{ "0": ["variables.files.0"], "1": ["variables.files.1"] }' \
-F 0=@./example/fileupload/testfiles/a.txt \
-F 1=@./example/fileupload/testfiles/c.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Got a working version using gqlgen, which has a file upload example 
https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/tree/master/example/fileupload

and looks to implement that via the spec at
https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec
Note this spec gives you a list of potential projects you can follow for the server and the client side per handling file uploads.

Example curl request, though based on how you implement it you may also need to include headers via -H.  Be careful not to have any whitespace after \ when you continue another line, else you will get errors like F: command not found). I include -v for more detail info and -L also so that if there's any redirects, you still properly get the output in the console.

```
curl -v -L http://localhost:8087/graphql \
-F operations='{ "query": "mutation($files: [Upload!]!) { multipleUpload(files: $files) { id, name, content } }", "variables": { "files": [null, null] } }' \
-F map='{ "0": ["variables.files.0"], "1": ["variables.files.1"] }' \
-F 0=@./example/fileupload/testfiles/a.txt \
-F 1=@./example/fileupload/testfiles/c.txt
```

This takes care of querying the server, I could also access it via Postman using a setup like below
[image: Postman configuration, file upload graphql query]

From the client side, if using apollo, a key point looks to be adding the project apollo-upload-client from https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client, replacing HttpLink with createUploadLink({ uri: ...}) in App.js, then restarting the client.  After I did that, the example component https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-examples/blob/master/app/components/UploadFileList.js finally worked for me.

Even though the mutation query says it uses Upload type, you do not need to create an interface for it, it should be handled from the server (hence, it seems if you get error messages similar to can't convert map [string] interface{} to Upload are not relevant to the actual error which is occurring)

Additional tips to get you started: When data is loaded in the graphql query, in golang, you can write the file by extracting content ([]byte) or which can be saved as a Blob to a sql server.

```
    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file.File)
    ...
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("/tmp/outputFile", content, 0644)
```

and when loading the file, you can load the data back in as a string, and then input in the writeFile func as  []byte(file.Content)

Comment: The payload works with multiple files, Thanks!!